# Trick XP into having more RAM?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, memory

Are there any way known to trick an computer with XP to appear to have more RAM?

I need to install a specific program (which fits in my system requirements), which is bundled with a number of other programs on an DVD.
Unfortunately, the other programs besides the one that I need demand twice the amount of RAM that's available on my computer and the installation is closed due to this. Can I trick my XP computer into have more RAM temporarily to bypass the block in the install executable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/354e46f8-4ffc-41d2-8156-6fd3e14cb7d3/) lists a few solution, my best bet is to fake the results of the method call with [WinDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).